# Is it possible to create a new instance of a command when needed using get in property?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I used next code

```
private String _Value = "hello";
//Set - just copy from value in _Value with PropertyChanged?.Invoke.
public String Value {get => _Value; set => Set(ref _Value, value);}

public ICommand DoSomeCommand{get => new SomeCommand(value);}
```

SomeCommand - the class that creates the command object, and saving value data.

```
get=>new SomeCommand(vale);
```

Initialize only ones at start of program, and keeps the value as "hello", even if i changed Value.
So i need to create new instance anytime my program calls the given command. As I understand it, all commands are stored in a buffer. But is it possible to have the command create a new instance with a new value when accessed?

For example, when i click on some button(which has this command) any time, new instance DoSomeCommand created and command with new value executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings are automatically updated only when the view is initialized or when the source property changes.

So if you want to keep your command implemented this way, you have to manually notify `PropertyChanged` event for your command when your `Value` property changes.

Possible implementation (assuming your `Set()` method returns `true` if the value changed):

```
private String _Value = "hello";
public String Value 
{
    get => _Value;
    set => 
    {
        if (Set(ref _Value, value))
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DoSomeCommand)));
        }
    }
}

public ICommand DoSomeCommand 
{
    get => new SomeCommand(value);
}
```